# Conversion a binario con javascript(duda logica)

Tags: javascript, lógica

Hace poco comencé con todo esto la programación, en este momento estoy realizando un script que me transforme un numero decimal en binario sin necesidad de usar  el & o el String. El error que me presenta es que al darle valores enteros me aproxima al valor mas alto sin embargo usar valor flotante no me arrojaria el resultado. un ejemplo

si uso un  while(a>=2) cuando ingreso el 24 Me hace todo bien hasta cuando llega al 3 porque hace 3%2=1 y hasta ahí bien pero al dividir 3/2=1.5 (1.5 lo aproxima a 2) y me genera un binario adicional;  pero si solo uso (a>2) me funciona bien con el numero 24 pero en el momento de ingresar otro numero como el 16 le quedaría faltando un binario que debería darse haciendo la operación de a%2 cuando a==2..

```
<script>
    var listabinario = new Array();
    alert("Bienvenido al programa");
    a = parseInt(prompt("ingrese el numero decimal: "));
    while (a > 2) {
        numero = parseInt(a / 2);
        b = parseInt(a % 2);
        alert(a);
        alert(b);
        listabinario.push(b);
        a = a - numero;
    }
    c = parseInt(a / 2);
    listabinario.push(c);
    alert(listabinario);

</script>
```

Comment: Julian bienvenido a SO, por favor edita el titulo por algo mas explicativo por ejemplo : "Conversión a binario con JavaScript" o algo mas puntual relacionado con tu problema. También te recomiendo leer [_**Como Preguntar**_](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: tu duda no es con javascript, tu duda es de logica, por favor aclara la pregunta para poder ayudarte respetando las normas de StackOverFlow

Comment: Esta otra respuesta de Stackoverflow te podria guiar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862608/1305745

Answer (score -4):

Lo que buscas lo tengo hecho en VB.NET y no en JAVASCRIPT Aquí va el código por si lo quieres traducir y mas abajo algunos ejemplos en java para hacer conversiones...

Public Function DeNumeroABinario(ByVal Numero As Integer) As String
        'If Numero < 1 Then DeNumeroABinario = "0" : Exit Function
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim ResultadoBin As String = vbNullString
        Dim ResTempo As String = vbNullString
        Dim ResTempoStr As String = ""
        If Numero > 1 Then
            ResultadoBin = vbNullString
            Do While Numero > 0
                ResTempo = Numero / 2
                ResTempoStr = "" + ResTempo
                If Right(ResTempoStr, 1) = "5" Then
                    ResultadoBin = "1" + ResultadoBin
                    Numero = ResTempo - 0.5
                Else
                    ResultadoBin = "0" + ResultadoBin
                    Numero = ResTempo
                End If

```
            If Numero = 0 Then
                ResultadoBin = "0" + ResultadoBin
                Exit Do
            End If
            If Numero = 1 Then
                ResultadoBin = "1" + ResultadoBin
                Exit Do
            End If
            If Numero = 0.5 Then
                ResultadoBin = "1" + ResultadoBin
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        ResultadoBin = Numero
    End If
    DeNumeroABinario = ResultadoBin
End Function
```

```js
function ConvertirBinario(Texto){
        var TextoConvertir = Texto;
        var Resultado = "";
        var Man = 0; 
        var Cuenta = TextoConvertir.length;
        var TempoLetra = "";
        for (Man = 0; Man < Cuenta; Man++){
            TempoLetra = CharsLeft(TextoConvertir, 1);
            Resultado = "" + Resultado +  CerosToLeft(NumeroABinario(CharToUnicode(TempoLetra)), 8);
            TextoConvertir = CharsRight(TextoConvertir, TextoConvertir.length - 1);
        }    
        return Resultado;
    }
    function CharsLeft(TextChars , NumChars){
    if ( typeof(TextChars) == "string" ){
        if ( typeof(NumChars) == "number" ){
           if (TextChars == ""){ exit(); }
           if (TextChars.length >= NumChars && NumChars >= 1 ){
               var Retorno = TextChars.slice(0, NumChars);
               return Retorno;
           }else{
               return TextChars;
           }
        }
    }    
}
function CharsRight(TextChars , NumChars){
    if ( typeof(TextChars) == "string" ){
        if ( typeof(NumChars) == "number" ){
           if (TextChars == ""){ exit(); }
           if (TextChars.length >= NumChars && NumChars >= 1 ){
               var Retorno = TextChars.slice(TextChars.length - NumChars,TextChars.length);
               return Retorno;
           }else{
               return TextChars;
           }
        }
    }    
}
function CerosToLeft(Number , CountCeros){
    if ( typeof(Number) == "string" ){
        if ( typeof(CountCeros) == "number" ){
            var StringNumber = "";
            var Longitud = 0;
            var Resultado = "";
            StringNumber = "" + Number;
            Longitud = StringNumber.length;
            if ( Longitud < CountCeros ){
                var Man = 0;
                Resultado = "" + StringNumber;
                for (Man=0;Man<CountCeros - Longitud ; Man++ ){
                    Resultado = "0" + Resultado; 
                }
                return Resultado;
            }else{
                Resultado = "" + StringNumber;
                return Resultado;
            }
        }
    }
}
function NumeroABinario(Numero){
    return Numero.toString(2);
}
```

Comment: A ver, vamos a ser claros. Estas haciendo 0 caso a los comentarios del resto de usuarios que te están recomendado leerte [answer] para que entiendas lo que haces mal. Si quieres responder y aportar al sitio, maravilloso. Pero **LEE**, las normas, [ask] , [tour] , [answer]. Te tienes que enterar de lo que estas haciendo bien y lo que estas haciendo mal. Para empezar, dar por asumido que el usuario de esta pregunta sabe traducir de vb.net a javascript esta fatal, debes respetar las etiquetas y el lenguaje de la pregunta. Si no vas a respetar las normas no respondas.